# UITabController causes iOS device to reboot

Tags: xamarin, ios9, xcode7

My app has been working normally with Xcode 6.x, iOS 8.x and the previous XS. I have now upgraded to the latest XS, Xcode 7 and iOS 9 and my app is REBOOTING the phone (not just crashing, but an actual black screen / apple logo reboot -kind-of-thing) every time I press any button from the main screen of the application and even when just tapping on a text field... instead of seeing the keyboard showing up, the device simply reboots.

I have narrowed down the issue to having a UITabController as the root view controller of the app.

To be more specific:

I have a UITabController that has three tabs. The tabs are navigation controllers that are tied to UIViewControllers. The UITabController is marked as "Is root view controller" in the storyboard.

If I delete the UITabController and navigation controllers and make any UIViewController as the root view controller, the issue goes away.

As soon as I have the UITabController as the "RootViewController", the app reboots the phone any time a button is pressed.

Please note that the exact same code works perfectly on iOS 8.4 even compiled with the latest version of XS and Xcode 7. It only does this on iOS 9.

XS: 5.9.7 (build 9)
Xcode: 7.0 (7A220)
OS X Yosemite, v. 10.10.5 (14F27)
iOS: 9.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. A bug in either XS/Xcode.

Had to delete the tab controller and re-add it. iOS 9 shouldn't reboot though.